# Recursive thinking

Tags: recursion

I would like to ask if it is really necessary to track every recursive call when writing it, because I am having troubles if recursive call is inside a loop or inside multiple for loops. I just get lost when I am trying to understand what is happening.
Do you have some advice how to approach recursive problems and how to imagine it. I have already read a lot about it but I havent found a perfect answer yet. I understand for example how factorial works or fibonacci recursion. I get lost for example when I am trying to print all combinations from 1 to 5 length of 3 or all the solutions for n-queen problem

Comment: You need to give a very concrete example of what you're trying to understand, and what you don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to think in recursive way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611275/how-to-think-in-recursive-way)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, try drawing a tree like structure that keeps track of each recursive call. Where a node is a function and every child node of that node is a recursive call made from that function.

Comment: I have been trying to do so, but it is hard to draw it for me when problem is more complicated

Comment: @Zokav in that case I'd say you have to give a more concrete example or you could try writing a program that draws the tree for you.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone may have a different mental approach towards towards modeling a recursive problem. If you can solve the n queens problem in a non-recursive way, then you are just fine. It is certainly helpful to grasp the concept of recursion to break down a problem, though. If you are up for the mental exercise, then I suggest a text book on PROLOG. It is fun and very much teaches recursion from the very beginning.

Attempting a bit of a brain dump on n-queens. It goes like "how would I do it manually" by try and error. For n-queens, I propose to in your mind call it 8-queens as a start, just to make it look more familiar and intuitive. "n" is not an iterator here but specifies the problem size.

- you reckon that n-queens has a self-similarity which is that you place single queens on a board - that is your candidate recursive routine
- for a given board you have a routine to test if the latest queen added is in conflict with the prior placed ones
- for a given board you have a routine to find a position for the queen that you have not tested yet if that test is not successful for the current  position
- you print out all queen positions if the queen you just placed was the nth (last) queen
- otherwise (if the current queen was validly placed) you position an additional queen

The above is your program. Your routine will pass a list of positions of earlier queens. The first invocation is with an empty list.